# How to aggregate a variable by date

Tags: r, date, missing-data, rolling-computation

I have an R dataset with columns:

- `date`
- `country_code`
- `version`
- `money`

The variable `money` is numerical. The variables `version` and `country_code` are categorical. Each combination of `date`, `country_code` and `version` defines a unique observation for which the value of `money` is meassured.

I want to group the variables `version` and `country_code` and compute 3 new variables in the dataset which are:

- money_week: For each observation, this variable stores the aggregation of the `money` along the previous 7 days.
- `money_15`: For each observation, this variable stores the aggregation of the `money` along the previous 15 days
- `money_total`: For each observation, this variable stores the aggregation of the `money`  up to the current date.

The different combinations of `country_code` and `version` may have different start and end dates, and there also may missing dates.

## Example

```
data = tibble(
date = seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-01-13'), by=1),
       money = 1:13)
data = data[-c(2,3,4,10,11),]

# [Some computations for adding the expected new variables]

# A tibble: 10 × 2
  date       money    money_week
2022-01-01     1          1
2022-01-05     5          6
2022-01-06     6          12
2022-01-07     7          19
2022-01-08     8          26
2022-01-09     9          35        
2022-01-12    12          42
2022-01-13    13          49
```

Observe that each observation is not simply the sum of the previous 7 observations, but the sum of the previous 7 days. So for example, the observation on date `2022-01-08` is the sum of observation on dates `2022-01-08`, `2022-01-07`, `2022-01-06`, `2022-01-05`, and it would include observations `2022-01-04`, `2022-01-03`, `2022-01-02` but those last are missing.

Comment: What about calculating cumulative sums of the year-weeks, `transform(data, money_week=ave(money, strftime(date, '%V'), FUN=cumsum))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `date` variable as an index for a sliding window function.

```r
library(slider)
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(money_week = slide_index_dbl(money, date, sum, .before = days(6)))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>   date       money money_week
#>   <date>     <int>      <dbl>
#> 1 2022-01-01     1          1
#> 2 2022-01-05     5          6
#> 3 2022-01-06     6         12
#> 4 2022-01-07     7         19
#> 5 2022-01-08     8         26
#> 6 2022-01-09     9         35
#> 7 2022-01-12    12         42
#> 8 2022-01-13    13         49
```

### More test data to show `money_15`

```
set.seed(123)
newdata = tibble(
  date = seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-03-31'), by=1),
  money = sample(1:20,90, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 60) %>%
  arrange(date)


newdata %>%
  mutate(money_week = slide_index_dbl(money, date, sum, .before = days(6)),
         money_15 = slide_index_dbl(money, date, sum, .before = days(14)),
         money_total = cumsum(money))
#> # A tibble: 60 × 5
#>    date       money money_week money_15 money_total
#>    <date>     <int>      <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>
#>  1 2022-01-01    15         15       15          15
#>  2 2022-01-02    19         34       34          34
#>  3 2022-01-03    14         48       48          48
#>  4 2022-01-05    10         58       58          58
#>  5 2022-01-06    18         76       76          76
#>  6 2022-01-07    11         87       87          87
#>  7 2022-01-08     5         77       92          92
#>  8 2022-01-09    20         78      112         112
#>  9 2022-01-11     5         69      117         117
#> 10 2022-01-13     9         50      126         126
#> # ℹ 50 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an overlap join to merge values from dates to intervals of dates (7 or 15 days, respectively):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define sample data
data = tibble(
  date = seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-01-13'), by=1),
  money = 1:13)

data = data[-c(2,3,4,10,11),]

# prepare intervals for overlap joins
df <- data |> 
  mutate(
    date = ymd(date),
    date_7 = date - days(6),
    date_15 = date - days(14)
  )

# merge by 7-day interval
sum_7 <- df |> 
  select(date, date_7) |> 
  inner_join(df, join_by(between(y$date, x$date_7, x$date))) |> 
  summarize(money = sum(money), .by = date.x) |> 
  rename(date = date.x, money_7 = money)

# merge by 15-day interval
sum_15 <- df |> 
  select(date, date_15) |> 
  inner_join(df, join_by(between(y$date, x$date_15, x$date))) |> 
  summarize(money = sum(money), .by = date.x) |> 
  rename(date = date.x, money_15 = money)

# bind cols
data |> 
  inner_join(sum_7, join_by(date)) |> 
  inner_join(sum_15, join_by(date))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   date       money money_7 money_15
#>   <date>     <int>   <int>    <int>
#> 1 2022-01-01     1       1        1
#> 2 2022-01-05     5       6        6
#> 3 2022-01-06     6      12       12
#> 4 2022-01-07     7      19       19
#> 5 2022-01-08     8      26       27
#> 6 2022-01-09     9      35       36
#> 7 2022-01-12    12      42       48
#> 8 2022-01-13    13      49       61
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>